# websocket (ws) to secure websocket (wss) Apache on Plesk (Centos) server

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, centos, plesk

I'm trying to make a secure websocket.
When i try with ws:// it's working fine but not with wss://

I've enabled mod_proxy and mod_proxy_wstunnel.
Added those line to Apache httpd.conf

```
ProxyPass /wss ws://127.0.0.1:8090
ProxyPassReverse /wss ws://127.0.0.1:8090
```

But still not working.

The website is using https, so FireFox won't allow a connexion to ws on https (for security reasons).

I'm not very use with wss and i wonder what should i do next ?

SSL Certificate is not auto-signed, but made with Let's Encrypt.

I'm managing socket with PHP and Javascript.

Looking for hours to a solution... can't find yet... still trying...

Thanks in advance for your help...

Fey

EDIT :
I'm now using WebSocketD : http://websocketd.com/ as a service. I installed it and configured it with systemCTL (so it starts with the server).

Very easy to use and reliable, works perfectly for wss :) .

Comment: Have you figured out the solution? Since I had to also faced a similar problem
 https://stackoverflow.com/q/53411060/7713811

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I'm facing same issue without success...

Comment: Yes, i add the solution by editing my post.